# Why can't I import User model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am building a django web app with a custom user model which extends the AbstractBaseUser. In one of my models I need to use this custom user model:

```
from accounts.models import User

class History(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
```

When I try to run the `python manage.py makemigrations` command this error message is outputted:

```
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

In my settings.py I do the following to let django know that there is a custom user model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.User"
```

I am puzzled as to what I am doing wrong. Surely there must be a way to import this model that I do not know of. How do I fix this?

I have tried to use the get_user_model() method, however it doesn't work in the model as the models haven't loaded yet. This is therefore not a solution. Any other ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you write `from accounts.models import User` in the `shell` ?

Comment: You probably have a circular import. Follow Gagik's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
class History(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) for more details.

> If you reference User directly (for example, by referring to it in a foreign key), your code will not work in projects where the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting has been changed to a different user model.
>
> get_user_model()[source]
>
> Instead of referring to User directly, you should reference the user model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). This method will return the currently active user model – the custom user model if one is specified, or User otherwise.
>
> When you define a foreign key or many-to-many relations to the user model, you should specify the custom model using the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting. For example

Comment: The docs say to do what I have done: `from myapp.models import CustomUser`

Comment: The place it says is when it describes custom user models in admin interface. Please click to documentation link I gave in the answer and see what it says. Will copy/paste some notes to answer as well shortly

Comment: I have changed the import statement to: `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` but there is an error which is: `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.` @Gagik Sukiasyan

Comment: Did you add you accounts app into INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'accounts',
    'jobs',
]`

Comment: move the accounts to be before the django.contrib.auth, otherwise it will not see, I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138567/discussion-between-gagik-sukiasyan-and-tom-finet).

Comment: Using the get_user_model() method doesn't work in the model as the models haven't loaded yet. This is therefore not a solution. Any other ideas? @Gagik Sukiasyan

Comment: I didn't try writing code and testing and I always used other way of extending the user, by creating other model by having one to one relation to auth user. But here I think the right solution is to use the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as I provided in my answer. Do you mean it also didn't work, or you only tried the get_user_model ?

Comment: No I have tried the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL method and it has worked. Thanks